# C# If statement variables not changing

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am starting to learn C# and at the moment, the variables aren't updating as I hoped to.

```
string  Carpet,
        tempCarpet;  
Double  carpetPrice;

do{
Console.WriteLine("What type of carpet do you want: ");
Console.Write("1. Berber ($3.75) | 2. Plush ($4.62) | 3. Barbed ($9.98)");
tempCarpet = Console.ReadLine();
if (tempCarpet == "1") {
    Carpet = "Berber";
    carpetPrice = 3.75;
} else if (tempCarpet == "2") {
    Carpet = "Plush";
    carpetPrice = 4.62;
} else if (tempCarpet == "3") {
    Carpet = "Barbed";
    carpetPrice = 9.98;
} else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection.");
}while(tempCarpet != "1"|tempCarpet != "2"|tempCarpet !="3"); 

Console.WriteLine("The Carpet" + Carpet + "costs {0:C}", carpetPrice);
```

`
It is coming up with an error saying Use of unassigned local variable. I want it to be in this sort of format because I want the option to choose which 'carpet' the person wants. Does anyone know of a solution around this problem?

Comment: Side note: your first lines in sample make no sense `Double = carpetPrice`

Comment: That is not valid C# code - please post actual code that compiles.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally put = when writing this question up. I edited my Question to reflect that.

Comment: Another side note: Your `while` condition is bitwise.. not logical. You want: `while(tempCarpet != "1" || tempCarpet != "2" || tempCarpet !="3");`

Comment: @SimonWhitehead after correcting the initializing of the variables and what you commented with the while statement, it does a loop where if I press 1 2 or 3, it still does the loop. Do you know what maybe the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring variables the wrong way :

```
string = Carpet,
         tempCarpet;  
Double = carpetPrice;
```

Correcr format of declaration is : `datatype var_name [ = value]`

Correcy way would be :

```
string Carpet = null, tempCarpet = null;
double carpetPrice = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing  `Carpet`  inside the condition and compiler can't determine whether the code will reach there. You may do

```
string Carpet = null;
```

Or you can assign it some default value in the last part of else.

Same is the case with `carpetPrice`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Double = carpetPrice;
```

to

```
Double carpetPrice;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not compilable code;

At the top:

```
string = Carpet,
                     tempCarpet;  
            Double = carpetPrice;
```

This should look something like

```
string carpet= "";
string tempCarpet = "";
double carpetPrice;
```

It would perhaps clear things up to assign the strings an initial value, to ensure that they are set before usage. The double is a different matter as it's a value type. Strings are reference types.

Comment: @Adriano Ok - fair point, I reworded my answer - I think as a learner it makes things easier to do it this way, but what I stated wasn't strictly true.

Answer (score 0):

this is Compiler Error

```
string = Carpet,
                         tempCarpet;  
                Double = carpetPrice;
```

Corrected Code:-

```
string Carpet = tempCarpet;
 Double = carpetPrice = 1020.00;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a switch for this.

```
  switch(tempCarpet){ 

case "1" : Carpet = "Berber";
            carpetPrice = 3.75;
    break;

case "2" : Carpet = "Plush";
            carpetPrice = 4.62;
    break;

case "3" : Carpet = "Barbed";
            carpetPrice = 9.98;
    break;
default : Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection.");
    break;

}
```

Comment: Me too but this actually doesn't solve his compiler error...LOL

Comment: Yes Atomsk, I saw...that's the reason of my comment. This doesn't answer to the question and for code review there is another site on StackEchange...

Answer (score 0):

There is wrong condition:

```
            }while(tempCarpet != "1"|tempCarpet != "2"|tempCarpet !="3");
```

Change to:

```
            } while (tempCarpet != "1" && tempCarpet != "2" && tempCarpet != "3");
```

But better way is:

```
string Carpet = null;
// ...
// There is some code
// ...
} while (null == Carpet);
```